# Troubles with select MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I got this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'and idcat = 00 OR idcat = 11 OR idcat = 4 OR idcat = 8 OR idcat
>   = 10 OR idcat ' at line 6

I tried to do this query on PHP

```
SELECT *,
        MATCH (name,description) AGAINST ('key') AS relevancia
  FROM offer
  WHERE
      MATCH (name,description)
          and idcat = 00
          OR idcat = 11
          OR idcat = 4
          OR idcat = 8
          OR idcat = 10
          OR idcat = 5
          OR idcat = 7
          OR idcat = 1
          OR idcat = 2
          OR idcat = 3
          OR idcat = 6
          OR idcat = 9
      AGAINST ('key')
  ORDER BY discount DESC
  LIMIT 0, 15
```

But if I try to do this query directly on phpmyadmin it works fine. So I don't know why does not work on PHP if it's same consultation .

By the way excuse my poor English.

**EDIT:**

This is the php consulation

```
$sql2 = "SELECT *, 
MATCH (name,description) 
AGAINST ('$search')
AS relevancia 
FROM offer 
WHERE MATCH (name,description) AGAINST ('$search')  
and  $wheres $order $limit";

echo $sql2;
mysql_query("".$sql2."")  or die (mysql_error());
```

The php result on $sql2

```
SELECT *, MATCH (name,description) AGAINST ('key') AS relevancia 
FROM offer 
WHERE MATCH (name,description) AGAINST ('key') 
and idcat IN(00, 11, 4, 8, 10, 5, 7, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9) 
ORDER BY discount DESC LIMIT 0, 3
```

Error in php-mysql

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
use near
'idcat IN(00, 11, 4, 8, 10, 5, 7, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9) ORDER BY discount DESC' at line 5
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT *, concat (name, relevance) AS relevancia 
FROM offer 
WHERE MATCH (name,description) AGAINST  ('key') 
and (idcat = '00' 
OR (idcat > 0 
and idcat<=11))
ORDER BY discount DESC LIMIT 0, 15
```

Comment: If you consider `idcat` to be a string type, as in `= '00'`, then the inequalities (`> 0` and `<= 11`) will be based upon a lexicographic order and may yield undesirable results (e.g. `'10asgf'`).

Answer (score 1):

You must not split the  [`MATCH (col1,col2,...) AGAINST (expr [search_modifier])`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) clause with your conditions on `idcat`.

Completely perform one first, *then* combine it with the other.  That is, either:

```sql
... WHERE MATCH (name,description) AGAINST ('key') AND idcat IN ( 00, 11, ... )
```

Or:

```sql
... WHERE idcat IN ( 00, 11, ... ) AND MATCH (name,description) AGAINST ('key')
```

*Note*: I have used MySQL's [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator as a shorthand for `(idcat = 00 OR idcat = 11 OR ...)`.

Comment: if `idcat=0` the match will return true..., I guess we need the table structure to help him...

Comment: @jcho360: Depends on the data type of the `idcat` column; in any event, nothing in this answer changes the logic of the OP's query (which was the caveat I was trying to add to your answer).

Comment: yeap, I like your answer it's shorter than mine, but I hope that ditoje give us the table structure to help him

Comment: It happens the same than before, from phpmyadmin it works fine, but doing this on php it doesn't works
The consultation is:

SELECT *, MATCH (name,description) AGAINST ('key') AS relevancia 
FROM offer 
WHERE MATCH (name,description) AGAINST ('key') 
and idcat IN(8, 10, 5, 7, 2, 6, 9) 
ORDER BY discount DESC LIMIT 0, 3

And idcat can be only numbers (intval)

Comment: @ditoje: Perhaps there's something wrong with your PHP code?  It might help if you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12785863/edit) your question to include the code you're using to invoke the query, together with any error message(s) you are seeing.